# Insert php variable inside array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, filter, foreach

I have a filter for the CPT and I need to manually type all custom taxonomy names inside the array():

```
sc_render_filter(
      'test',
      'All Categories',
      array( 'Category One', 'Category two', 'Category three'),
      ''
      . ($current_sub_brand ? ( 'sub_brand=' . $current_sub_brand . '&' ) : '' )
      . ($current_varietal ? ( 'varietal=' . $current_varietal . '&' ) : '' )
      . ($current_publication ? ( 'publication=' . $current_publication . '&' ) : '' )
      . ($current_vintage ? ( 'vintage=' . $current_vintage . '&' ) : '' )
    );
```

Is it possible somehow to use the variable or foreach loop inside array() to automatically generate terms or names? Or maybe I need another approach?
This is what I have in foreach:

```
$source = '';
    foreach ($termslist as $term) { 
        $source .= "'". $term->name. "'". ',';
    }
    echo rtrim($source, ',');
```

Comment: it seems to me that your trying to accomplish something but you maybe be going about it a bad way. 

What is the end goal of this, they may be a easier less messy way - to answer you, it is possible using a Foreach and logic to create a script to do that but again it will be messy and probably not the best way to do it.

Comment: You want to replace this array, `array( 'Category One', 'Category two', 'Category three')`, right? Then why are you assembling stuff in a string variable - instead of adding it to an array? `$source = []; foreach(...) { $source[] = ...; }`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuntely for your project, it is appropriate to use variable variables (which I do not typically endorse).  Using variable variables is a symptom that array data is not properly stored as such.  The fact that you have individual `$current_` variables looks to be an earlier problem to address.

In the meantime, you can loop through the know keys and dynamically access these variables.  When finished, call `http_build_query()` to cleanly, reliably generate a url querystring string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MvvDA))

```
$keys = ['sub_brand', 'varietal', 'publication', 'vintage'];
$data = [];
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $data[$key] = ${'current_' . $key};
}
$queryString = http_build_query($data);

sc_render_filter(
    'test',
    'All Categories',
    ['Category One', 'Category two', 'Category three'],
    $queryString
);
```

The querystring string looks like this:

```
sub_brand=foo&varietal=bar&publication=boo&vintage=far
```